# Python: Fastest way to find list of words [with n-grams] in text conversations

Tags: python, text-mining, n-gram

Am looking for how many times all words in word list are found in an conversation. Not considering individual frequency of each word but just the total count. The word list includes ngrams uptill 3

```
from nltk.util import ngrams
find = ['car', 'motor cycle', 'heavy traffic vehicle']
data = pd.read_csv('inputdata.csv')
def count_words(doc, find):
    onegram = [' '.join(grams) for grams in ngrams(doc.split(), 1)]
    bigrams = [' '.join(grams) for grams in ngrams(doc.split(), 2)]
    trigrams = [' '.join(grams) for grams in ngrams(doc.split(), 3)]
    n_gram = onegrams + bigrams + trigrams
    ''' get count of unique bag of words present in doc '''
    lst = ".".join([i for i in find if i in n_gram])
    cnt = np.count_nonzero(np.unique(lst.split(".")))
    return cnt
result = data['text'].apply(lambda x: count_words(x, find))
```

this steps are very  process heavy and take long time to run in case of large datasets. what are options to optimize present approach or are there other alternative steps?

Answer (score 0):

First, split the doc *once*, not three times on each call.

```
def count_words(doc, find):
    word_list = doc.split()
    onegram = [' '.join(grams) for grams in ngrams(word_list, 1)]
    ...
```

Second, you can count nicely using the collections [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) class.  Then counting is trivial in your code, and as fast as Python can make it.